# Creating hierarchy using id and parentid

Tags: javascript

Possible duplicate, but this one unlike other questions does not wish to hook objects to another. I would want to create a new objects/array containing the hierarchy data

So I have these datasets:

```
var sets = {
    'dataSet1': {
        'ID': '1',
        'ParentID': '0'
    },

    'dataSet2': {
        'ID': '2',
        'ParentID': '1'
    },

    'dataSet3': {
        'ID': '3',
        'ParentID': '1'
    },

     'dataSet4': {
         'ID': '4',
         'ParentID': '3'
    }
}
```

I want to loop through them and dynamically create a hierarchy by using ID and ParentID. The result of the process I would like to output into something like:

```
var tiers = {
     'tier1':[
     {
        'parentid':'0',
        'id':'1'
     }
     ]

    ,'tier2':[
     {
        'parentid':'1',
        'id':'2'
     },
     {
        'parentid':'1',
        'id':'3'
     }
     ]
    ,'tier3':[
     {
        'parentid':'3',
        'id':'4'
     }
     ]
}
```

Basically the tier object will hold tier arrays containing objects that have the id and the parent id fields.

So when I access the data all I have to do is get them via tiers['tier2'][1]. All I need to do is structure the data into a hierarchy. Note: Native js

This is my current attempt, but this only works for the one in the top of the hierarchy, the second tier and below are the biggest problem

```
var datasetobj = sets;
var hierarchy = tiers;
for (x in datasetobj) {

        if (datasetobj[x]['ParentID'] == 0) {
            hierarchy['tier1'].push({
                'parentid': datasetobj[x]['ParentID'],
                'id': datasetobj[x]['ID']
            });
        }

    }
```

Now this is fairly easy if I'm going to use static approaches by limiting the number of tiers the program can handle, and then checking each ID then inserting tiers. But that's not exactly the OOP approach of doing things.

Comment: I've tried things that didn't work lol haha. I tried using classic for loops and conditions but I can't seem to structure-ize the code into the correct ones

Comment: post your try/ failed attempt of solution

Comment: The failed attempts were complete garbage so I actually trashed the codes now. :(

Comment: I've posted a sample code of what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem requires traversing your dependency tree while keeping track of the depth. You can solve the problem using a [depth-first-traversal](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Depth-first_search) implemented using recursion and incrementing the depth.

**Update:** Alright, you wanted some more explanation, some more explanation you'll get.

> Also, can you provide some links to where I can study these kinds of concepts? Your approach is very new to me

This problem cam be solved using [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)). I'll explain the code and drop in some links to the concepts.

---

## Transform `sets` to `hashMap`

The first thing I'm doing is transforming your `sets` object to another object which I'm calling `hashMap`. I'm transforming it to this form because it will make "look-ups" faster when we're creating the `tier` object.

Here is the `sets` object for reference:

```
const sets = {
  'dataSet1': {
    'ID': '1',
    'ParentID': '0'
  },

  'dataSet2': {
    'ID': '2',
    'ParentID': '1'
  },

  'dataSet3': {
    'ID': '3',
    'ParentID': '1'
  },

  'dataSet4': {
    'ID': '4',
    'ParentID': '3'
  }
};
```

And I perform this transformation:

```
const hashMap = (Object
  // 1
  .keys(sets)
  // 2
  .map(datasetKey => ({
    originalKey: datasetKey,
    id: sets[datasetKey].ID,
    parentId: sets[datasetKey].ParentID
  }))
  // 3
  .reduce((hashMap, value) => {
    // 4
    const hashMapKey = 'hasParentId' + value.parentId;
    // 5
    if (!hashMap[hashMapKey]) {
      hashMap[hashMapKey] = [];
    }
    // 6
    hashMap[hashMapKey].push(value);
    // 7
    return hashMap;
  }, {})
);
```

which results in this object:

```
{
  "hasParentId0": [
    {
      "originalKey": "dataSet1",
      "id": "1",
      "parentId": "0"
    }
  ],
  "hasParentId1": [
    {
      "originalKey": "dataSet2",
      "id": "2",
      "parentId": "1"
    },
    {
      "originalKey": "dataSet3",
      "id": "3",
      "parentId": "1"
    }
  ],
  "hasParentId3": [
    {
      "originalKey": "dataSet4",
      "id": "4",
      "parentId": "3"
    }
  ]
}
```

So step by step:

1. Use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get an array of keys from the object `sets`
2. Use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to map each key of the array create from calling `Object.keys` to a new object. This object has 3 properties: `originalKey`, `id`, `parentId`
3. Use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to *reduce* the array of mapped objects (created in the last step) into a single object. The first parameter of `Array.prototype.reduce` is a "reducer" function that takes two arguments. The first argument of the "reducer" function is an "accumulator" and the second argument is an item from your array. The reducer will be called multiple times, one call for each item in the array. The reducer function returns an accumulator and that accumulator will be used in the next call of this inner function (so all the items of the array reduce into the accumulator). The second argument of `Array.prototype.reduce` is the initial accumulator. In this case, the initial accumulator is an empty object `{}`.
4. Inside the reducer function, we create a string `hashMapKey`. This string will be used as the key to the accumulator.
5. This transformation expects every `hashMap[hashMapKey]` to be an array. Here we check to see if the value at `hashMap[hashMapKey]` is an array and if it isn't we make it one.
6. Now that we know there is an array at `hashMap[hashMapKey]`, we can push the `value` on that array. Remember that the `value` is an object we mapped from step 2.
7. Return the modified `hashMap` to be used as the "accumulator" of the next "reducer" call.

When the reduction is finished, the `hashMap` contains the correct transformation. The transformation to `sets` to `hashMap` is required for fast lookups in the next step.

## Transform `hashMap` to `tier`

The above structure has an implied [graph](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/graph_theory/graph_theory_fundamentals.htm) where each node (aka point) is an object from `sets` and each edge is a directed relationship via the property `ParentID`.

In order to create the structure you want, you need to perform a [depth-first-traversal](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/depth-first-traversal-for-a-graph/) traversing this graph while keeping track of the depth.

Here is the code:

```
// 1
const tier = {};
let maxDepth = 0;

// 2
function traverse(currentParentId, depth) {
  // 3
  if (depth > maxDepth) {
    maxDepth = depth;
  }
  // 4
  const childrenOfCurrentParent = hashMap['hasParentId' + currentParentId]

  // 5
  if (!childrenOfCurrentParent) {
    return;
  }

  // 6
  childrenOfCurrentParent.forEach(value => {
    // 7
    const tierKey = 'tier' + depth;
    if (!tier[tierKey]) {
      tier[tierKey] = [];
    }
    // 8
    tier[tierKey].push(value);
    // 9
    traverse(value.id, depth + 1);
  });
}
```

1. create an empty object to store the tiers. Optionally create a variable for the hold the max depth. This is useful if you want to convert the tiers object into a tiers array.
2. define a function `traverse` that takes two arguments: `currentParentId` and `depth`. The `currentParentId` is the key used to identify the id of the current parent. **This function is initially called with a `currentParentId` of `0` and a `depth` of `0`.** This will make more sense once we look at the implementation of the code.
3. Reassign `maxDepth`
4. Grab the `childrenOfCurrentParent` from the lookup table. See why we made it? Looking up values in this table is very fast :)
5. If there isn't any `childrenOfCurrentParent`, don't do anything.
6. Use [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to iterate through the `childrenOfCurrentParent`. The `value` again is the `value` of the mapped objects from the transformation.
7. create a `tierKey` to store the `value` in. If the array isn't initialized, initialize it.
8. push the `value`
9. **Use [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)), call the `traverse` function again from within itself changing the `currentParrentId` and incrementing the `depth`. Repeat from step 3 until there are no more items to be placed.** This is depth-first-traversal.

---

## Transforming `tier` to `tierArray`

I think this one is self-explanatory. Since the tiers are a set of ordered items, it might be better to store it in an array. This is why we kept track of the `maxDepth`.

---

## Working snippet

```js
const sets = {
  'dataSet1': {
    'ID': '1',
    'ParentID': '0'
  },

  'dataSet2': {
    'ID': '2',
    'ParentID': '1'
  },

  'dataSet3': {
    'ID': '3',
    'ParentID': '1'
  },

  'dataSet4': {
    'ID': '4',
    'ParentID': '3'
  }
};

// `hashMap` is a data transform
// see the `console.log` of this transform
const hashMap = (Object
  // grab the keys of the object `sets`
  .keys(sets)
  // then map every key to a new object
  .map(datasetKey => ({
    originalKey: datasetKey,
    id: sets[datasetKey].ID,
    parentId: sets[datasetKey].ParentID
  }))
  // reduce the new objects into a single object
  .reduce((hashMap, value) => {
    // create a key to store the `value`
    const hashMapKey = 'hasParentId' + value.parentId;
    // if `hashMap[hashMapKey]` isn't initialized yet,
    // initialize it to an array
    if (!hashMap[hashMapKey]) {
      hashMap[hashMapKey] = [];
    }
    // then push the value (the objects created above)
    hashMap[hashMapKey].push(value);
    // return the hashMap
    return hashMap;
  }, {})
);

console.log('hashMap', hashMap);

// create an object to store the `tier`s in.
const tier = {};
// keep track of the `maxDepth` in case you want to transform `tier` to an array
let maxDepth = 0;

// this is a recursive function to traverse your graph
// this implements a depth-first-traversal keeping track of the `depth`
function traverse(currentParentId, depth) {
  if (depth > maxDepth) {
    maxDepth = depth;
  }
  const childrenOfCurrentParent = hashMap['hasParentId' + currentParentId]

  // if there are no children of the currentParent
  if (!childrenOfCurrentParent) {
    return;
  }

  childrenOfCurrentParent.forEach(value => {
    const tierKey = 'tier' + depth;
    if (!tier[tierKey]) {
      tier[tierKey] = [];
    }
    tier[tierKey].push(value);
    traverse(value.id, depth + 1);
  });
}

// call the function to start the traversal
// using 0 as the first `currentParentId` and
// using 0 as the first `depth` value
traverse(0, 0);


// the tier object is now created
console.log('tier', tier);

// but it might be more natural to have `tier` as an array
const tierArray = [];
for (let i = 0; i < maxDepth; i += 1) {
  tierArray[i] = tier['tier' + i];
}

console.log('tierArray', tierArray);
```

Phew, what an answer. Hope this helps!

Comment: This works perfectly, I'll comment again if I don't understand some parts. For now, I don't understand anything.

Comment: I can't seem to decipher this, will be waiting for the explanation :)

Comment: @Merigold alright, I just got home. give me a few minutes

Comment: Also, can you provide some links to where I can study these kinds of concepts? Your approach is very new to me, and I strictly have to understand your code because I'm using this for work -- otherwise I have to look for a simpler approach -- which is probably a needle in a haystack

Comment: What a guy, I can see that you really love your career. Thanks for the answer! Will read this later after our break ends.

Comment: Also, is there a way to make this compatible with IE11? I have tried removing the arrow notations and changing it to classic function return but IE can't seem to properly detect other syntaxes too -- while everything works in Chrome, Firefox and Edge

Comment: @Merigold paste it into [here](https://babeljs.io/repl/). babel compile new javascript into older javascript :D

Comment: Please be relieved to know that all your efforts did not go to waste, I have almost understood everything now. I am extremely grateful. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your if condition in your for loop. It only proccess the top level element `if (datasetobj[x]['ParentID'] == 0) only processes parent id 0`.

To get what you're after dynamically create hierarchy arrays and remove the if condition. Do something like:

```js
      var tiers = {};
      var sets = {
        'dataSet1': {
            'ID': '1',
            'ParentID': '0'
        },
    
        'dataSet2': {
            'ID': '2',
            'ParentID': '1'
        },
    
        'dataSet3': {
            'ID': '3',
            'ParentID': '1'
        },
    
         'dataSet4': {
             'ID': '4',
             'ParentID': '3'
        }
    };
    var datasetobj = sets;
    var hierarchy = tiers;
    for (x in datasetobj) {
            if (datasetobj[x]['ParentID']) { 
                var idx = 'tier'+datasetobj[x]['ParentID'];
                if(!hierarchy[idx])
                    hierarchy[idx]=[];
                hierarchy[idx].push({
                    'parentid': datasetobj[x]['ParentID'],
                    'id': datasetobj[x]['ID']
                });
            }
        };
    console.log(tiers);
```

Comment: This almost got it, the 1st and 2nd tiers generating the data perfectly, but the data on the 3rd tier is in the 4th tier, leaving the 3rd tier empty

Comment: I'm sorry I removed the answer, it actually still have the problem. This almost got it the problem is it is creating tiers based on the ParentID fields -- since I have nothing hooked on my ParentID = 2, there is no tier2 and only tier3 as I have a child for ParentID = 3