# Set nested value of object without knowing amount of keys given

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function that can get an array of an arbitary size, along with a value. The function should apply the keys given, to an object that has nested objects, and then set the last key to the value given. It then stores the object somewhere elsewhere.

This is easily done when the amount of keys is known, and consistent (`object[key1][key2][key3] = value`), however it seems impossible to do this when the amount of keys given is unknown.

I know I can't do something like this

```
let foo = object[stack[0]];
stack.slice(1).forEach(key => foo = foo[key]);
foo = value;
```

Because that will just end up reassigning `foo`.
What I want to do is to be able do something like `object[stack] = value`, or something similar.

**EDIT**
It seems that people are interpreting this as *getting* a nested value, which is not what I want. I want to *set* a nested value.

Example data for those that asked

```
let stack = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
let object = {
    a: {
        b: {
            c: {
                d: 'Lorem'
            }
        }
    }
}

// Do something that sets object.a.b.c.d to 'Lorem ipsum' (that isn't reliant on the number of keys)

console.log(object);
/*
    {
        a: {
            b: {
                c: {
                    d: 'Lorem ipsum'
                }
            }
        }
    }
*/
```

Comment: So you have an array of keys and you want some efficient way to apply each key consecutively to get the final nested value?

Comment: This is a little confusing can you be a bit more clear? Maybe show us a bit more data or what you array might possibly look like that you are getting back

Comment: A little confusing question but I am guessing you would need to use recursive with this. I have had a similar problem that was solved by recursion.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44103268/creating-hierarchy-using-id-and-parentid

Comment: Edited question to include example data.

Comment: Can you include sample output as well, what you would expect the output to be given the sample data.

Comment: Edited to include what the output should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that I can't search as well as I think I can, and that I don't understand JavaScript pointers as well as I probably should.

I managed to find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18937118/8778928) which does exactly what I wish.

Simplified and edited version to deal with what I need

```
let stack = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
let object = {
    a: {
        b: {
            c: {
                d: 'Lorem'
            }
        }
    }
};
let ref = object; // This becomes a pointer to `object`.

// Loop through all the keys and change `ref` so that it becomes a pointer to each nested value.
stack.slice(0, -1).forEach(key => ref = ref[key]);

// Sets the last given key.
ref[stack.slice(-1)[0]] = 'Lorem ipsum';

console.log(object);
/*
    {
        a: {
            b: {
                c: {
                    d: 'Lorem ipsum'
                }
            }
        }
    }
*/
```